# Package javax.xml.registry.infomodel.* What is it for? Forget or implement?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, standards

Looking through Java [EE6 API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html) I've found interesting package [javax.xml.registry.infomodel](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/registry/infomodel/package-summary.html), containing such interfaces as

- PostalAddress (having city, street, zip ...)
- Organization (having users, child structures, contacts, phone numbers)
- PersonName (first/last/middle name)
- EmailAddress
- TelephoneNumber (country/ area codes, type, extension, etc)
- User (person name, web page, address, etc)
- ....

As it's stated in API,

> This package describes the
>   information model for [JAXR](http://java.sun.com/webservices/jaxr/jaxr-1_0-fr-spec.pdf) API

which is dated April 2002 and, in turn, in it's abstract says:

> Currently there are numerous
>   overlapping specifications for
>   business registries. Examples include
>   ISO 11179, OASIS, eCo Framework, ebXML
>   and UDDI. JAXR provides a uniform and
>   standard API for accessing such
>   registries within the Java platform.

Most of Java developers are dealing with these entities every day, implementing them in their own way.

Meaning this top, infomodel, level of the package with widely known entities, when should we consider implement them? Potentially google-sized projects? Interfacing with ERP systems? Or is it that our world is moving towards standardization and it's becoming a matter of good manners, or even requirements, to follow these standards? Can it be that in a couple of years customer will call to me and say 'I want everything to be ebXML compliant, now!' and I'd say 'I am already!' ?

Is JAXR something growing and promising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXR is not something you use for HelloWorld application, it is upon you (or you client) to use it or not. If you have found that growing of the project will require access to XML registry, just implement them.

Is it something growing and promising? Definitely YES, for now JMX provides you with a single set of APIs to access a variety of XML registries, including UDDI and the ebXML Registry. You don't need to worry about the nitty-gritty details of each registry's information model! Try to imagine how much time it saves.

JMX abstraction is consistent with the Java philosophy of *Write once, Run Anywhere*. It enables value-added capabilities beyond what the underlying registries can do.

As an example, a non-JAXR UDDI client can't do taxonomy browsing and taxonomy-aware smart queries -- which are available to a JAXR client for UDDI.

If you want to know more about future plans of registration and discovery of web services using JAXR ask directly Farrukh Najmi (JAXR Specification Lead) or David J. Etelson (Java Strategy and Product Marketing), may you have a luck and they answer you ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, if your customer doesnt specify any kind of business registry I wouldn't implement it. Basically because you cannot charge him for something he didn't needs.

Bye.

Comment: It looks a bit different. I'm already charging him, and will charge future customers for almost the same Address and Company objects in my app. Should I  make my Person and Organization objects fully JAXR-ready (at almost no cost), that's the question. Is JAXR something growing and promising or just byte[] in .pdf format?